# Axios request for one component on the server side

Tags: vue.js, axios, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

How is it possible to do in a vue component an axios request on the server side. The component should show the results from the axios response (it's a large response, so the server side should be more performant that the client side).

```
<template>
  <div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    ...
  },

  ...
}
</script>
```

I've tried the lifecycle methods created and mounted, but both are running on the client side (and the created one also on the server). Is it possible to do some axios requests for one component on the server side?

Comment: Have you tried async-data? https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do it in Nuxt.
You can user the `asyncData` method:

```
<template>
  <div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    ...
  },
  async asyncData (context) {
    // here you have access to app, store, axios if you use it, etc
    return yourData // your data will be available as a data
  }

  ...
}
</script>
```

You also have the possibility to use `middleware`. It works the same way that the asyncData method and you can also use it in a page component, but you can use it in a global way so it can be executed at every page change (useful to redirect the user under certain conditions for example)

More infos: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/